# Call javascript in sharepoint custom field

Tags: sharepoint-2007, custom-fields

I am creating a custom field in SharePoint 2007. I have seen other solutions where the current site URL was default value of a text field.

**How can I get this current site URL?
I have got one answer whiches states that I shall use JavaScript, but where do I put the script?**

I hope you can help.

BR

## To answer 1

I am new to SharePoint and am not quiet sure where to put the java script. Normaly i just give the initial value to the field in the FieldEditor.cs file but how can I do this with the javascript?

Here follows a picute of my files.

[image]

I have tried to put it into FiledEditor.cs but this results in the value of myString is written in the top of the web page.

### Here is my current code:

```
string myScript = "var currentUrl = document.URL; LabelLookupFieldTargetURLText.Text = currentUrl;";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(LabelLookupFieldTargetURLText.GetType(), "LabelLookupFieldTargetURLTextJavaScript", myScript);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self. I don't need to use a java script. I can just use SPContext.Current.Site.Url

Answer (score -1):

use javascript:
var nowUrl = document.URL;
yourTextfiled.value = nowUrl;

you can read this:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: looks easy but where do I put the java script? I have just added some information to the question if  that helps you answer my question.